# php array_filter and mysql SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php, mysql

Have not found answer so asking.

From html textarea get such array

```
Array
(
    [persons_to_check] => 
One person

Another person
Third person
)
```

Here is one blank row (line). I want to remove it. So

```
$array_from_textarea01 = 
array_filter( explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST['persons_to_check'])) );
```

Then mysql

```
SELECT `Column` FROM `some_table` 
WHERE `AnotherColumn` IN 
('. rtrim(trim(str_repeat ('?,', count($array_from_textarea01))),','). ')

$stmt_select_un->execute( $array_from_textarea01 );
```

And get `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

```
$stmt_select_un->execute( array($array_from_textarea01) );
```

And get `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

See no error if array from textarea is without blank line.

```
Array
(
    [persons_to_check] => 
One person
Another person
Third person
)
```

Also no error if

```
foreach ( 
array_filter( explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST['persons_to_check'])) ) 
as $val ){ 
$array_from_textarea01[] = trim($val);
}
```

Please, advice what solution, the only solution is `foreach`? And why without `foreach` i get error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't know this, but just recreated this and the problem is down to the indexes of the array.  When you use `array_filter()` you may end up with a sparse array, but the `execute()` is expecting the values to be from 0 and up sequentially.

Simple solution is to use `array_values()`...

```
$stmt_select_un->execute( array_values($array_from_textarea01 ));
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Yes, array keys after remove was like 0, 2, 3 and key 1 i removed. Ok, thanks